# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: EmployeeInfo.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to run this code. It's meant to search for the file EmployeeInfo.txt. That file is in the same folder as the .java file. However, I keep getting the error message displayed in the title saying it can't find the file. I'm probably doing something stupidly wrong. Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DoPayroll {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File ("EmployeeInfo.txt"));

        for (int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++) {
            payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
        }

        diskScanner.close();

    }

    static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner) {

        Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

        anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
        anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
        aScanner.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be in the main package folder, along with `src` file (same dir), not inside the src file.